# Как посчитать количество рядов матрицы, где все елементы < 0?

Tags: c#

Задача звучит следующим образом:
Определить количество строк, не содержащих ни одного положительного элемента;

```
int n, m;
Random rnd = new Random();
double min = -5.4, max = 5.7; // диапазон

Console.WriteLine("Введите количество рядов: "); // проверка n
while (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n) == false)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Произошла ошибка, повторите!");
    continue;
}
Console.WriteLine("Введите количество колонок: "); // проверка n
while (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out m) == false)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Произошла ошибка, повторите!");
    continue;
}

double[,] array = new double[n,m]; // матрица

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // заполнение
{
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        array[i,j] = rnd.NextDouble() *  (max - min) + min; // диапазон
        array[i, j] = Math.Round(array[i, j], 1); // округление до 1 знака после ,
    }
}
    
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // вывод
{
    double sum = 0;
    int sumIndex = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) 
    {
        if (array[i,j] < 0) // ОШИБКА в условии, как указать что если хоть 1 элемент > 0, условие не срабатывает 
        {
            sumIndex += 1;
        }

        sum += array[i,j];           // сума элементов каждого рядка
        sum = Math.Round(sum, 2);   // округление сумы
        Console.Write($"{array[i,j]} \t");
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Сума столбца {i} = {sum}; Количество елементов меньше нуля = {sumIndex}");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Пример роботы программы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вопрос то вы и не задали.

Comment: @CrazyElf исправил)

Comment: Так. И в чём сложность? Подсказка - вы можете создавать и использовать переменные. Например, перед проходом по строке сделать флаг, который будет означать выполнение условия по этой строке и положить в него `true`. Потом идёте по строке... Ну, подумайте хоть немного сами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это должно было быть просто:

```
int rowsCount = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // вывод
{
    // ... ваш код

    if (sumIndex == m)
        rowsCount++;
}

Console.WriteLine($"Количество строк, где все элементы отрицательные = {rowsCount}");
```

Comment: Это и правда оказалось слишком просто, я долго просидел но почему-то такая мысль мне не пришла в голову, а комментарий с флагом совсем сбил меня с мысли, спасибо вам!